# preg_match numbers and comma

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some values like 4,3 or 5 for instance.

I want to allow only the numbers (from 0 to 9) and the comma.

I found this function, pregmatch but it's not working correctly.

```
<?php
$regex="/[0-9,]/";
if(!preg_match($regex, $item['qty'])){
// my work
}
?>
```

What's wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Corrected syntax:

```
$regex="/^[0-9,]+$/";
```

`^` represents start of line

`+` represents one or more of the group characters

`$` represents end of line

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

`'~^\d+(,\d+)?$~'`

It allows e.g. `1` or `11,5` but fails on `1,` or `,,1` or `,,`

- `^` Start of
- `\d+` followed by one or more digits
- `(,\d+)?` optional: comma `,` followed by one or more digits
- `$` end

`\d` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit `[0-9]`

You asked what's wrong with `$regex="/[0-9,]/";`

It would match any `0-9` or `,` which are in the [[characterclass](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)]. Even, when matching a string like `abc1s` or `a,b` because **no [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)** are used.

Comment: nice but try '~^\d+(,\d+)*$~' so that it will match more than two values

Answer (score 1):

If you know it will be a comma-separated list then use `explode()`:

```
<?php

// test item with incorrect entries
$item = '1,2,3,4,d,@,;';

// explode whatever is between commas into an array
$item_array = explode(',', $item);

// loop through the array (you could also use array_walk())
foreach($item_array as $key => $val)
{
    // to clean it
    $item_array[$key] = (int) $val;

    // use the values here
}

// or here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $regex = '/^[0-9,]+$/';
    if(!preg_match($regex, $item['qty'])) {
        // my work 
    }
?>
```